# how to pass a python list in place of * in sql query

Tags: python, sql, pandas

i have this type of sql string

```
"""select {}  from public."myTempTable" where desc_id in (select desc_id from projectapp_description_table)
Except 
select  {}   from projectapp_sitelink_table"""
```

and i want to pass a python list in parenthesis for execution

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
column_list = ['id', 'user', 'value']

my_string = 'select {0} from public.myTempTable where desc_id in (select desc_id from projectapp_description_table) ' \
            'Except ' \
            'select  {0} from projectapp_sitelink_table'.format(", ".join('%s' % col for col in column_list))

print(my_string)
```